# MySQL Query for Subtraction of 2 fields with decimal(13,2)

Tags: mysql

How do you subtract (2)two different fields with the same data type of `decimal(13,2)` ?

I have table for `users`

attribtues:

`id, name, password, email, deleted, created_at, updated`

and

table for `top_up_history`

attributes:

`id, userId, paymentId, paymentDesc, amount, deleted, created_at, updated_at`

and

table for `transaction_details`

`id, userId, merchId, transId, amount, refCode, procId, deleted, created_at, updated_at`

and

I have `view` for `user_balance`

attributes:

`userId, total_topup, total_balance`

Here's my current query:

```
 SELECT a.id as userId, SUM(b.amount) as total_topup, 
 SUM(b.amount) - SUM(c.amount) as total_balance
 FROM `users` AS a LEFT JOIN `top_up_history` AS b
 ON a.id = b.userId LEFT JOIN`transaction_details` as c
 ON a.id = c.userId GROUP BY a.id
```

Now the current output of this `user_balance` is  this:

[image]

But the problem is

the data from `transaction_details` is:

[image]

the data from `top_up_history`

[image]

the data from `users`

[image]

There's something wrong with my computation.

The output should be:

`userId      total_topup     total_balance`

`1           NULL             NULL`

`2           NULL             NULL`

`3           15000            14,725`

`9           10150             9,875`

Comment: share table definitions and sample data so that someone can help you.

Comment: You shouldn't share as a image format, it should be text, Create stmt for table and insert stmt for data samples will do. So that they can check locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take a look at resulting table without `GROUP BY` function.

[image]

`LEFT JOIN top_up_history` produces two rows for each unique user,

It caused by repeated userId values (9 and 3) in `top_up_history` table. At this moment (before joining `transaction_details`) you already have 6 rows. Now sql joins `transaction_details` and duplicates its `amount` column value for each matched row.

Then, finally you group, and sum duplicated values. Substruction itself works ok.

The easiest way to deal with that kind of problem is to do subquery like so:

```
SELECT a.id as userId, SUM(b.amount) as total_topup,
       SUM(b.amount) -
       (select sum(tr.amount) from transaction_details_ as tr where tr.users_id = a.id) as total_balance
FROM users_ AS a
  LEFT JOIN  top_up_history_ AS b ON a.id = b.users_id
  LEFT JOIN transaction_details_ as c ON a.id = c.users_id
GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: This is what I'm actually trying to do. Thanks for the Idea :) This helps me a lot

Answer (score 2):

you should manage the null value

```
  SELECT a.id as userId
    , SUM(ifnull(b.amount,0)) as total_topup
    , SUM(ifnull(b.amount,0)) - SUM(ifnull(c.amount,0)) as total_balance
  FROM `users` AS a 
  LEFT JOIN `top_up_history` AS b  ON a.id = b.userId 
  LEFT JOIN`transaction_details` as c  ON a.id = c.userId 
  GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: you missed it `ifnull(c.amount,0)`

Comment: @James  you are welcome  ..  suggestions and useful comments are always very welcome